# How can I use the '&' as a search criteria in a url

Tags: javascript, html, url, search

This is my first post, so don't mind me if it is a repeat, but I couldn't find an answer.

I'm working with javascript/html/abl/css, etc and I have to be able to use the & as a search criteria.

I need a way to get something like http://this.com/mode=results&action=search&result='&'& to work.

The problem that I'm having is that the url keeps interpretting it like a seperator, and the page breaks. I've tried to convert it to a %26 or a & to try and keep it in the search, but then it won't find my search. I looked at google's url when search for & and it's replace by %26. Any opinions?

Thanks, Sheldon.

Comment: Only change the `&` you need as values to `%26`, not all of them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_in_a_URI

Comment: I'm not changing all of them, just the ones that are getting added in a search field. So you have a search field that some searches test&test. I currently have it changing to test%26test, but then it's not finding my result. I'll check the encoding thing first to see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the javascript encodeURIComponent() Function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: Thanks for that. It made it simpler than manually changing it. It only fixed one problem however. The url and page will work now, but the database query is derping at me because of the &, thinking it's the logical AND.

Answer (score 0):

You *will* need to escape `&` in the URL in order for the character to not be treated as a separator. And as you stated, the correct encoding is `%26`. Perhaps you need to make an additional change on the server to ensure the encoded char is processed correctly?